# Explain signed angle calculation between 2 face normals

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces

I am working on this project where I am using Blender and need to calculate the signed angle between the faces that meet at each edge. So, I found this edge angle functionality provided by Blender and it seems to work.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/read/edge_angle.html

However, I want to understand how this function works. Looking at the code: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/main/source/blender/nodes/geometry/nodes/node_geo_input_mesh_edge_angle.cc#L151 for SignedAngleFieldInput, it seems to do the following:

1. Calculate the normals for the 2 connected faces: face1 and face2
2. Find the centerpoint of the edge
3. Get the centerpoint of  face2 and subtract the edge centerpoint to get a tangent normal for face2.
4. Get the concavity by taking the dotproduct of face1 normal and face2 tangent

I don't really understand steps 2 and 3. What does the tangent normal represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centerpoint of the edge is calculated by taking the average of the two vertices that make the edge. This edge is the edge where the two faces meet as stated in the docs for Edge Angle. In other words this centerpoint is the middle of the intersection of the two faces.

The centerpoint of face2 subtract the edge centerpoint gives a vector that goes from the edge centerpoint to the centerpoint of face2. I.e a vector tangent to face2. In fact the tangent vector is normalised so this tangent vector is of unit length.

The dot product of face1 normal and face2 tangent will be positive when the faces are concave. When the angle between the face1 normal and face2 tangent becomes greater than 90 degrees the dot product becomes negative and the faces are not concave.

The sign of this dot product determines whether the angle returned is positive (the faces are not concave) or negative (the faces are concave).

---

**Further explanation**

For vectors $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ the dot product is given by, $$\boldsymbol{a}\cdot\boldsymbol{b}= \Vert\boldsymbol{a}\Vert \Vert\boldsymbol{b}\Vert \cos\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$.

Imagine face1 and face2 are both facing upward i.e both are lying flat, then the face1 normal will point directly upwards and the face2 tangent will be at 90$^\circ$. Since $\cos\theta$ is positive for $0< \theta < 90^\circ $ the dot product will be positive if the faces were to fold upwards slightly  (thus becoming concave) since $\theta$ would be less than $90^\circ$

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why the dot product of face1 normal and face2 tangent will be positive when the faces are concave? Sorry, I am a bit rusty with my linear algebra and geometry.

Comment: No problem. I corrected an error in the third paragraph (180 should have been 90) and added some further explanation. Hope that helps